# Maintain proportion of a sprite in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I added a sprite with a PNG image to a 16:9 scene in Unity. When I view the scene on the iPad (4:3 aspect ratio) it appears distorted. How can I make the sprite maintain it's proportion?

The image on the iPad:

[image]

On the computer (in Unity):

[image]

Here are my settings.

[image]

I tried using this script for the camera but it didn't work it just enlarges the character and it was still distorted. ([source](https://www.frispgames.com/best-practices-for-handling-different-aspect-ratios-and-screen-resolutions-in-unity-2D-for-mobile-games/)):

```c#
using UnityEngine;

public class PixelPerfectCamera : MonoBehaviour {

    public float pixelsToUnits = 100;
    private Camera camera;

    void Awake () {
        camera = Camera.main;
    }

    void Update () {
        camera.orthographicSize = Screen.height / pixelsToUnits / 2;
    }
}
```

I am using the sprite in a 2D scene using Unity 5.

Comment: Can you add a snap of what image looks like on both screen resolutiosn

Comment: You need to adjust the camera ortographic size based on the resolution.
This is what you need https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yI8JrBNTwkc

Comment: @UmairM Just added a picture.

Comment: @Fiffe I tried this one, didn't work: https://www.frispgames.com/best-practices-for-handling-different-aspect-ratios-and-screen-resolutions-in-unity-2D-for-mobile-games/

Comment: @Idan Shechter There's a lot of Pixel Perfect camera scripts on the internet and even on the asset store, you probably got the outdated one or did something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **preserve aspect** option of the image.
[image]

Comment: If I need to make the image interactive, will this solution will be good? The sprite doesn't have this option, it's only for the image control. If I add an Image control to the sprite and set Preserve Aspect, it still appears distorted.

Comment: @Idan Shechter You shouldn't be using both Image and Sprite. Are you using the image for UI?

Comment: Then, you should use SpriteRenderer. For SpriteRenderer aspect ratio is not the issue, you can scale it however you like. Your problem is I guess resolution issue. You should try with high res icon.

Comment: I used sprite renderer in the first place and this is where I have the issue. When I app runs on the iPad, it shows a distorted image of the Knight.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the sprite on a UI/Image which requires a rect transform component resulting it resize according to screen. Use sprite renderer on empty object.

One way to create this is using menu:

**GameObject->2D Object->Sprite**

Hope this helps